# When using char** to copy string from source to destination, the destination string is showing empty in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am passing the string from the source to the destination. I took the Destination string as char**

And from my "chararrycpy" function I am passing the char** destination string as dest[0].

Is it the correct way to pass dest[0]?

**Because eventhough commonstringcopy setting the destination string dest[0] is showing empty.**

**could someone please help on this?**

```
commonstringcopy(char* dst, const char* src,rsize_t  destsz,rsize_t  count)

{
// Here using strncpy_s and setting the destination string
}



bool chararraycpy(const std::string& source, char** dest)
{

    const size_t size = source.length() + 1 ;
    char *destCopy = new char[size] ;
    (*dest) = destCopy;
    memset((dest[0]), 0, size) ;

    commonstringcopy((dest[0]), source.c_str(),size,source.length());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `*dest` (or just `destCopy`) would be more idiomatic than `dest[0]` in this case, but I don't see any reason this shouldn't work. Show how you invoke this function, the contents of `commonstringcopy()`, and how you are displaying the string.

Comment: No need to call `commonstringcopy`, if you would instead call `memcpy(*dest, source.c_str(), size)` instead of `memset`.